# How do I know if my flags are being looked at, when no judgement is being issued?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-reproduced, flags

I have a flag that is still labeled as "active" over two weeks after I submitted it. (Submitted on 2013-11-22.) I wouldn't think that any single moderator - let alone the whole moderator team - on any site would be ignoring the flag queue for more than a couple days at a time on a regular basis. So, I can only hope that this just means the moderators have looked at it but chosen not to act in one way or another for whatever reason.

However, this does leave the impression that the moderator team may actually *not* care. On a site that's languished in beta for nearly three years already, this is an easy assumption to make. However, the moderators here have all been "seen" by the site within the past couple days and most of them have some sort of posting activity within the past week. So, I'd really like to not believe that.

It may be very possible that the item I have flagged isn't quite so close-worthy as I thought, but at the same time my flag isn't so far off-base as to be judged unhelpful. But, if this is the case, what should be done to give the user an indication that their flags *are* being attended to in a timely manner?

Comment: I don't see your flag, so I presume it was already processed.

Comment: added the bug tag. this sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your flag by looking at your user profile (it wasn't showing up in the mod flag list for some reason). I've closed the question now.

Comment: Well, that's odd. Thanks. I wonder if we could figure out why it wasn't showing up? 'Cause if it's not just me... that could be bad.